# TSql to Linq translation

Tags: linq-to-sql, translation

how can I translate this to Linq to SQL

I want to get all message responses (mr) but for each number in mr I only want messages that were received after the 1st message (m) was sent

```
 select mr.*
     from 
      (select distinct PhoneNumber, MIN(SentDate) as MinSentDate
        from Messages 
        groupby PhoneNumber)m, 
        join        
        MessageResponses mr on m.PhoneNumber = mr.PhoneNumber

        where mr.ReceivedDate > m.MinSentDate
```

tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this

```
var query = from m in (from me in context.Messages
                       group me by me.PhoneNumber into mgr
                       select new
                       {
                         PhoneNumber = mgr.Key,
                         MinSentDate = mgr.Select(x => x.SentDate).Min()
                       }).Distinct()
            join mr in context.MessageResponses
            on m.PhoneNumber equals mr.PhoneNumber
            where mr.ReceivedDate > m.MinSentDate
            select mr;
```